# 1 to Many relationship in OOP php

Tags: php, oop, one-to-many

I need a little guidance before I spend a few hours restructuring and find out that this isn't a good way to do something.  My program is for a 1 to 1 initiative in a school district.  I have a database of all the assignments, the student, and the computers.  I am building an object oriented design to make coding some things more uniform (and for all the other benefits).  This application will be used to guide a user through the takeup and laptop check process.  Here is my dilemma.

A student (object) can have one or two current assignments (one being a loaner the other a permanent).  I initially built a student object, an assignment object, and a device object.  Then, when the student is created we use a lookup factory to find the current assignment(s) that student has outstanding.  I then loop through these from within the student construct and create an array of assignment objects which each looks up the device information.

This works great and gets all of the information that I need but I am finding it difficult to work with since there is an array of assignment objects and there are certain rules to follow logically.

A loaner assignment (one given when the original computer has been sent off for problems) must be turned in FIRST. And, in general, it gets difficult to determine which assignment object in this array has properties I need to know.

So, my IDEA (which may not be a good idea) is to break this out to a 1 to 1 to 1 to 1 relationship.  Student to assignments to assignment to device.

Then if I need to know if the student has a loaner assignment I could make a function inside the assignments object and call `student->assignments->hasLoanerAssignment()`

What do you think internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are saying that loaner assignments are different from permananent assignments, and that this is causing complication. If so then you may want to use inheritance. Loaner and permananent assigments would then be two types of Assignment and you can give them their own properties and methods.

```
class Assignment 
{
    // instance of Device
    protected $device

    // instance of Student
    protected $student  
}

class LoanerAssignment extends Assignment 
{
    // various properties and methods relevant to loan
}
class PermanentAssignment extends Assignment 
{
    // various properties and methods relevant to permanent
}
```

Assuming you are keeping this data in a database, make separate tables for Loaner and Permanent and then it will be easy to add a method to Student to see if it has a loaner assignment, e.g.:

```
// in Student class
function hasLoanerAssignment()
{
    return 1 === $yourChosenDBAdaptor->getCountOfLoanerAssignents($this->_studentId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I cannot change the database schema without breaking a different program that is already in production.  The assignments table contains all assignments and has a field called 'loaner' which is boolean (tiny int) to denote a loaner assignment or a permanent assignment.

Comment: That doesn't matter really. You can still use inheritance at the PHP level.

Comment: Yes this is true.  I think this is an acceptible solution.  I would then store boolean functions like hasLoanerAssignment and hasPermanentAssignment in the student object and it would check if $loaner and $permanent were null.  Thanks